# Use tidyverse to find difference between base model run and all others

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks something like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(Model = rep(c("OM", "EM-1", "EM-2", "EM-3"), each = 3),
              Run = rep(c(1,2,3), time=4),
              Value = c(2,10,5,20,26,7,8,15,33,11,31,7))
```

Where I have values from multiple models across several runs, in this case 4 models with 3 runs each.  The "OM" model is the base case and I would like to compare everything back to it.

I would like to, using tidyverse, calculate a new value which would be the difference between each model run and its corresponding "OM" model run.  I think I am getting close with:

```
library(tidyverse)
 x <- dat %>%
      group_by(Run)  %>%
      filter(!is.na(Value)) %>%
      mutate(Diff = c(NA, diff(Value)))
```

Which calculates the difference between Runs of subsequent models but I cant figure out how to get all of these calculations to be in relation to the "OM" model, instead of just whatever the previous model was.  I know I can do this by subsetting my data and doing the calculations that way but I am trying to do it cleanly in tidyverse since I will have lots of different models over time and don't want to have to subset all of them to run calculations.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grouping by 'Run', we subset the 'Value' where 'Model' is not 'OM' and subtract from those that are 'OM', append `NA` (for the 'Value' difference corresponding to 'OM' difference with itself) in `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
   group_by(Run) %>%
   mutate(Diff = c(NA, Value[Model!= "OM"] - Value[Model == "OM"]))
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups: Run [3]
#   Model    Run Value  Diff
#   <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 OM      1.00  2.00 NA   
# 2 OM      2.00 10.0  NA   
# 3 OM      3.00  5.00 NA   
# 4 EM-1    1.00 20.0  18.0 
# 5 EM-1    2.00 26.0  16.0 
# 6 EM-1    3.00  7.00  2.00
# 7 EM-2    1.00  8.00  6.00
# 8 EM-2    2.00 15.0   5.00
# 9 EM-2    3.00 33.0  28.0 
#10 EM-3    1.00 11.0   9.00
#11 EM-3    2.00 31.0  21.0 
#12 EM-3    3.00  7.00  2.00
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% 
 spread(Model, Value) %>% 
 gather(Model, Value, -Run, -OM) %>% 
 mutate(Diff = Value - OM)
#  Run OM Model Value Diff
#1   1  2  EM-1    20   18
#2   2 10  EM-1    26   16
#3   3  5  EM-1     7    2
#4   1  2  EM-2     8    6
#5   2 10  EM-2    15    5
#6   3  5  EM-2    33   28
#7   1  2  EM-3    11    9
#8   2 10  EM-3    31   21
#9   3  5  EM-3     7    2
```